# How to pass variables from one jsp to other without making them session variable?

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

I have a website which would be having around 15 session variables per user. I recently came to read an article which says that "session variables are evil and they affect the performance of the application". I was really disappointed by reading that article as I couldn't find any other way through which I can access the variables on other page.

Consider the below scenario,

I have a forum website in which when a user clicks a particular question, `ForumSingleQuesitonController` is called which stores the question, its answers, the comments of questions and answers both within the object of `ArrayList<ForumSingleQuestionBean>` and this object is stored by me in the session.

Now I use `resonse.sendRedirect("pages/forum_single_question.jsp");` to goto the `forum_single_question.jsp` page, from which I access the session variable and prints out it's values.
Now my question is how can I perform this procedure i.e. passing a variable from `Controller(Servlet)` to `JSP` without using session variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Passing a variable from controller?  Are you using Spring or do you mean servlet?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I mean Servlet

Comment: Is there any reason your not using a forward?

Comment: @KevinBowersox well I heard it is better to use redirect rather than forward. Is that correct?

Comment: if you don't want to use sessions because they're evil, I think you'll have to pass request parameters via GET/POST. Personally, I don't think sessions are THAT evil :-)

Comment: It depends on the situation, if they are posting a form the redirect is better to prevent double form submissions if the back button is used.  Are they actually submitting data through a form?

Comment: No, it's not correct at all. A redirect is better after a successful post, to avoid reposting the request when refreshing or navigating back in history. But the redirect should go to a controller, not to a JSP. JSPs should never be accessed directly. They are the view in Model-View-Controller. The request goes to a controller, which stores the model into the request, and forwards to a view.

Comment: @Leo me neither man but here is the link which says they are http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/Advanced/faq4.shtml

Comment: @SaumilSoni don't believe on everything you read on the web ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend performing a `forward` from the servlet.  This will pass all of the request parameters to the JSP.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/forum_single_question.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

If you need to include additional attributes set them prior to the forward using:

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName", value);
```

Comment: Damm, I guess I've to do a lot of work to convert all those redirect to forward ;)